# Mac to Windows Compatibility with an R Script Calling Bash

Tags: r, windows, bash, macos, compatibility

**Current script**

I work on `Mac OSX`. I have an R script that I like to use to organize my files and produce .pdf via LaTex. In order to (1) produce the .pdf with LaTeX and (2) manipulate some files and directories I use Bash script from R with `system("")`.

**From Mac to Windows**

I would like to offer this R script (once compiled to make an executable) to someone that knows nothing about programming and uses Windows. I have no idea how the windows prompt commands work and what language it uses. I am afraid that (1) I cannot use the function `system("")` on Windows and (2) I cannot use bash such as `system("rm dir/file.txt")`.

**Question**

What do you think would be the easiest for me in order to make my script compatible with Windows (given that I know nothing about Windows)? Will I be able to use `system("")` and Bash from R on Windows?

Comment: Depending on what it is you want to do it might be sufficient to use R commands in place of `system` / bash commands so that platform differences are automatically taken care of.  The tools package has `texi2pdf` to convert latex to pdf.  Also the R commands documented in `?files` may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution is to handle both cases separately (keep in mind that windows paths are also different from unix paths).

```
if(.Platform$OS.type == "unix") {
  system("rm dir/file.txt")
  [...]
} 
else {
  system("DEL /Q dir\file.txt")
  [...]
}
```

You should have no problem searching for unix equivalent commands in windows cmd.

Also keep in mind that if you need the R script to exec LaTeX binaries, it would pretty much kill the portability because of the huge dependencies that LaTeX has.